# Why "incomplete type error" in C++ do not hold for nested classes

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
    B b() const { return B();}    
};

class B
{   
    A a() const { return A(); }    
};
```

it produces the following error:

```
 In member function 'B A::b() const':
error: return type 'class B' is incomplete
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class B'
error: forward declaration of 'class B'
```

But if I put this code inside another class definition like so:

```
class C
{
class A;
class B;

class A
{
    B b() const { return B();}    
};

class B
{   
    A a() const { return A(); }    
};
};
```

Compiler do not complain anymore.

Question: why it is ok in second case but wrong in first?

Comment: Context matters, and it works the same way that you can call any member function or use any member variable even if they haven't been declared yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason a member function may access a variable declared bellow it in the class body. From the standard, emphasis mine:

> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#mem-6) A class is considered a completely-defined object type
>   ([basic.types]) (or complete type) at the closing } of the
>   class-specifier. Within the class member-specification, **the class is
>   regarded as complete within function bodies**, default arguments,
>   noexcept-specifiers, and default member initializers (**including such
>   things in nested classes**). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete
>   within its own class member-specification.

So inside `A::b`, the full class definition of `C` is a given. And that includes the full class definition of `B`, so you may create an object of that type.